# Repeating Data and Incorrect Names in Pandas DataFrame count Function Results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a question about the Pandas DataFrame `count` function.

I'm working on the following code:

```
d = {'c1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'c2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'c3': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'Animal': ["Cat", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog"]}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So I end up with `DataFrame` `df`, which contains the following:

```
    c1  c2  c3  Animal
0   1   1   1   Cat
1   1   1   1   Cat
2   1   1   1   Dog
3   1   1   1   Cat
4   1   1   1   Dog
```

Columns `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` contain information about my Animal collection which is not relevant to this question. My goal is to count the number of animals by species, i.e., the contents of the `Animal` column.

When I run:

```
df.groupby("Animal").count()
```

the result is a `DataFrame` that contains:

```
        c1  c2  c3
Animal          
Cat     3   3   3
Dog     2   2   2
```

As you can see, the desired result, counting the number times `Cat` and `Dog` appear in column `Aninal` is correctly computed. However, this result is a bit unsatisfying to me for the following reasons:

1. The counts of `Cat` and `Dog` are each repeated three times in the output, one for each column header `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.
2. The headers of the columns in this resulting `DataFrame` are really wrong: the entries are not `c1`, `c2`, or `c3` items anymore (those could be heights, weights, etc. for example), but rather animal species **counts**. To me this is a problem, since it is easy for client code (for example, code that uses a function that I write returning this `DataFrame`) to misinterpret these as entries instead of counts.

My questions are:

1. Why is the `count` function implemented this way, with repeating data and unchanged column headers?
2. Is it ever possible for each column to be different in a given row in the result of `count`?
3. Is there are cleaner way to do this in Pandas that addresses my two concerns listed above?

I realize the following code will partially address these problems:

```
df.groupby("Animal").count()['c1']
```

which results in a Series with the contents:

```
Animal
Cat     3
Dog     2
Name: c1, dtype: int64
```

But this still isn't really what I'm looking for, since:

1. It's inelegant, what's the logic of filtering on `c1` (or `c2` or `c3`, which would result in the same Series except the name)?
2. The name (analogous to the argument with the column header above) is still `c1`, which is misleading and inelegant.

I realize I can rename the Series as follows:

```
df.groupby("Animal").count()['c1'].rename("animal_count")
```

which results in the following Series:

```
Animal
Cat    3
Dog    2
Name: animal_count, dtype: int64
```

That's a satisfactory result; it does not repeat data and is reasonably named, though I would have preferred a DataFrame at this point (I realize I could covert it). However, the code I used to get this,

```
df.groupby("Animal").count()['c1'].rename("animal_count")
```

is very unsatisfying for elegance and length.

Another possible solution I've found is:

```
df.groupby("Animal").size()
```

which results in:

```
Animal
Cat    3
Dog    2
dtype: int64
```

however it's not clear to me if this is coincidently correct or if `size` and `count` really do the same thing. If so, why are both implemented in Pandas?

Is there a better way to do this in Pandas?

Thanks to everyone for your input!

Comment: I've also tried:     `df.agg({"Animal": "count"}).rename(columns={"Animal": "COUNT"}).groupby("COUNT").size()`

This gives me a satisfactory result as a Series:

`    COUNT
    Cat    3
    Dog    2
    dtype: int64`

However, to me it's still inelegant code. 

To get a reasonable name, I use the `rename` function explicitly. Otherwise, the title will not be count or something else that is reasonable and will imply that something else is afoot, creating logic and usability issues.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I've further noticed that only `DataFrameGroupBy` objects have useful `size` functions, and not normal `DataFrame`s. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The count function counts (for each column as you've noted) the number of non-na / non-empty cells. In general, this could differ for each column if they have different missing values. After a groupby though, I don't think this would ever be the case.

Like you mentioned though, I believe .size() is the function you want to just get the size of each grouping. I think this should also exist on a normal DataFrame, but it looks like it's a property not a function there (since it just returns a single number of rows; its not a mapping to apply to each group)